# Unexpected behaviour in Express form validation router

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, forms, express

I have this code in a `router.post` which will validate my input form with the help of ajax:

```
if(req.body.firstname === '' || req.body.firstname !== req.body.firstname.match(/\D+/g)[0]) {
  console.log('AJAX ERROR: Firstname is empty and/or have a number.');
}
else if(req.body.captcha !== req.body.captcha.match(/^kettő$/igm) ||
        req.body.captcha !== req.body.captcha.match(/^ketto$/igm) ||
        req.body.captcha !== req.body.captcha.match(/^two$/igm)) {
  console.log('AJAX ERROR: captcha is empty and/or the entered value is invalid.');
}
else {
  console.log('AJAX ERROR');
};
```

Expected output:

- if `firstname` is empty, than throw error in `console.log`
- if `firstname` has numbers, than throw error in `console.log`
- if `captcha` is not equal to `kettő, ketto, Kettő, Ketto, KETTŐ, KETTO, two, Two, TWO` answers, than throw error in `console.log`
- Othervise if these requirements are not met, throw `else`.

Experienced behaviour:

- `captcha` always throwing error to `console.log` after when `firstname` is validated. `firstname` works as expected.

I also experiencing serious lag after many re-request in a row with the following console error: `main-vanilla.min.js:1 POST http://127.0.0.1:3000/hu/form net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Answer (score 1):

```
else if(req.body.captcha !== req.body.captcha.match(/^kettő$/igm) ||
        req.body.captcha !== req.body.captcha.match(/^ketto$/igm) ||
        req.body.captcha !== req.body.captcha.match(/^two$/igm)) {
  console.log('AJAX ERROR: captcha is empty and/or the entered value is invalid.');
}
```

has a couple things wrong with it:

1. You are missing the `[0]` after the `.match()` which you do have in the `firstname.match()`. `match()` returns an Array so you need to select the first element.
2. Right now the logic says if one of these does not match, then throw an error. What you actually want is, if none of these match, throw an error. You should use `&&` instead of `||` to achieve that.